# Delete and image on button click using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, web

i want to delete an image from s simple HTML page, when the delete button is pressed. I hav tried following code but it is not working, help please.

```
<script>
 function del()
 {
 var Node1 = document.getElementById(“i”);
 Node1.removeChild(Node1.childNodes[0]);
 alert("Image deleted");
 }
 </script>

<img src="file:///C|/Users/momo/Desktop/uf.PNG" id="i"/>
<button onclick="del()">Delete Image</button>
```

Comment: You need to use real quotes too

Comment: where should i use them?

Comment: Here. I do not know how you got curly quotes (“i”);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your code:

```
 var Node1 = document.getElementById(“i”);
 Node1.removeChild(Node1.childNodes[0]);
```

your `Node1` variable has no child nodes so it will never work, you need to use that on the `parent` node... But I wonder, **wouldn't hide it fit your problem?**

```
document.getElementById('i').style.display = 'none';
```

if not, you need to know what is the parent node of that image and then use `removeChild` correctly.